# Router has internet, does assign IPs to clients, clients can not browse or wget

Tags: linux, networking, router, dns

I am dealing with an extremely annoying problem that I do not have the know-how for to fix apparantly. The situation is as follows:

- Received new router, fibre internet was installed
- Connected router, WiFi appears, connect PC with Ethernet, correct internet speed shown on router panel.
- Mobile phones, when connected, give the warning "connected but no internet".
- From the desktop I did the following (Fedora machine):

1. Tried adding nameservers to resolve.conf
2. Tried adding nameservers to the other Linux system service (the newer one)
3. Tried ping to:

   - 8.8.8.8: WORKING
   - 1.1.1.1: WORKING
   - google.com: WORKING
   - digitalocean.com: WORKING
4. NSLOOKUP works to google.com and digitalocean.com.
5. Can also access my router settings at: 192.168.1.1

What does not work:

- Accessing any website
- Accessing a website by typing the IP address
- Doing a wget from an IP (non-local IP)

At this point I have sank three days in fixing this, currently not able to work which is costing me so any help would be greatly appreciated especially in these inflationary times.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Superuser . If the issue is only on this new router it obviously might be related to this router not being set up correctly, but in order to be able to even try to help you with that you'd need to specify the router details.

Comment: Hi! The router is: Sagemcom 5366s Fibre Box. I have also tried a different router but the internet would not work with that one. I can check again.

Comment: If it doesn't work with another I'd venture to say it's something with ISP. Maybe you just need to pay the bill.

Answer (score -1):

on linux:

clear arp cache

ip -s -s neigh flush all

clear dns cache:

figure out which dns service you are using:

sudo lsof -i :53 -S

For systemd-resolve:

$ sudo systemd-resolve --flush-caches

OR

$ sudo resolvectl flush-caches

For dnsmasq:

sudo killall -HUP dnsmasq

or if dnsmasq is runing as a service:

$ sudo systemctl restart dnsmasq

## On SysVinit systems

$ sudo service dnsmasq restart

then just for good measure, restart networking:

sudo systemctl restart networking

on windows:

settins->network->scroll to bottom->click "reset network"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).